# REST API POST Response after multiple objects are created?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm creating tasks with various properties and I'm passing the JSON data from Angular frontend to Java based backend. Assignee is a property of the Task class at the moment.
A new request came in to change the behavior: The user should be able to select multiple assignees upon creating a new task.

The way I want to handle this is that I want to create the same amount of tasks as the number of assignees passed. So if *n* users are passed with the various task data, *n* tasks would be created in the DB for each user as an assignee.

Previously I could only pass one assignee and the code for returning the POST request's response was the following:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response save(TaskInDto taskInDto) {
    // saving to DB, etc... 
    String taskId = createdTask.getId().toString();
    URI taskUri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(taskId).build();
    return Response.created(taskUri).build();
}
```

My question is regarding REST design: **What should I return as a Result object to the user if multiple objects were created?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a POST request is creating multiple objects, clients will expect back a response entity containing links to each created resource.

Comment: Is there a conventional way to do this (Like using the Response builder class) or should I switch from returning a Response to a custom JSON object?

Comment: You can either add `link`s or you can embed links in an envelope in the response entity.

Comment: Can you point me to the solution how it can be done with Jersey API in java? I can't find the proper methods..

Comment: If you're adding to an envelope, that's just another property of the entity. If you're adding them directly, the method is the trivial-to-find ResponseBuilder#link().

Comment: Or the representation of both newly created objects.